# moving django project to google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am trying to move a django project to google appengine. So I followed http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html . But

```
django.dispatch.dispatcher.connect(
    log_exception, django.core.signals.got_request_exception)

django.dispatch.dispatcher.disconnect(
    django.db._rollback_on_exception,
    django.core.signals.got_request_exception)
```

was giving me error saying can't find dispatcher.connect/dispatcher.disconnect . So I changed the code as

```
django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal.connect(
    log_exception, django.core.signals.got_request_exception)
```

But now , when I am running the application , I am getting following error

> *File "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py",
>   line 2208, in ExecuteOrImportScript
>       exec module_code in script_module.**dict**   File
>   "C:\Personal\Study\Python\twtApp\src\main.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       import django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal
>   ImportError: No module named Signal*

As it's said the google article , I have copied django folders to top level folder of my projects .

Is there anything I am missing ?

Pls help ..

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies in Python being unable to import the Signal module. Make sure it's properly in your path, and that it isn't somehow missing from your Django install.

I would strongly recommend that you use the google-app-engine-django project instead. You'll have a lot more luck.

http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/

Comment: Check out django/despatch/dispatcher.py  in django1.2.1. You will find django.dispath.dispatcher.Signal.connect

Comment: Why are you trying to get Django running on App Engine without using the linked project? You do understand that the ORM doesn't work at all, right?

Comment: I am not using ORM here . It's just a study project. grabs data from one websource and do some calculations and shows up the results. No data storage . Could you pls tell more about linked project ? I am working on windows .

Comment: The linked project basically attempts to clean up all the loose ends (like what you've been running into) to make Django run cleanly on app engine. The Google article you linked to is really old, and hasn't been a reliable way to get things running in quite some time.